# How to change the Canvas Render Camera via C#

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two camera. One which is the main camera and another that follow an object.

The main camera is attached to a canvas with HUD and other GUI Text stuff. When I change the camera to the object that need to be followed, I loose the canvas. I clearly need to change the Render Camera inside the Canvas component.

[image]

I've tought that something like this would exist

```
canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>().renderCamera...
```

but it's not. So how can I change the render camera via script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's this one:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-worldCamera.html

```
canvas.worldCamera = someOtherCamera;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign to the Canvas.worldCamera

Doesn't make sense but that's the way it is!